# Determine if a new file(s) was added to job1 in Jenkins by retrieving past 2 successful build logs/console text in job2

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am fairly new to Jenkins and currently stumped with this. the only way I have been able to tell if anything was added is by checking the build log and comparing it to the last successful build log. At the end of the job it transfers the files to a new location, and once done with all transfers it tells me the number of total files transferred.  It doesn't say which files were transferred in the logs, so I still need to find a way to id them.

I currently have been trying to use a second job to compare the 2 logs, but I can't figure out how to get the last 2 successful build logs (any build logs actually).  Is there any way that job2 can access the build logs/console text of job1?

Comment: Why do you need to know if anything was added?

Comment: because if anything was added I need to send an email notification with what was added to make it easier/quicker to update the system for everyone.  Not fully in the know as to whats going on with it or why but that's the jist of it.  I know how to send the email if I can identify what was added.

Comment: Can you not identify that by inspecting the VCS commit(s) corresponding to the build?

Comment: not entirely sure. the change log in the repo never has any history of a file being added because only so many logs are kept.  I had this thought as well at one point but don't know how I would implement it